# Detect keydown?

Tags: rust, keyboard, keyboard-events, rust-cargo

I would like to detect a keydown event in Rust and then check if a combination of keys is pressed, in order to do further actions based on that.
So basically support **keyboard shortcuts** in my Rust application.

I've looked at some crates for example *ncurses* but they did not match my requirements...

Comment: Keyboard handling is system specific, it depends on what kind of program you are writing: if it is a console or GUI, if it is Windows, Linux, Mac, WebAssembly or whatever, if you use a toolkit or the native bindings...

Comment: I would like to support Windows, Linux and Mac. I currently use web-view as my gui and wanted to detect keypresses on system level.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Best solution for ANSI terminals (Linux, macOS)

If you don't need support for Windows then the best is **[termion](https://crates.io/crates/termion)**.

It's a library for manipulating the terminal. In which you can detect key events and even **keyboard shortcuts**. And it's also really lightweight! Only **22.78 kB** (as of version 1.5.5).

Here's a quick program I put together to showcase few shortcuts.

Add this code to `main.rs`, add `termion = "1.5.5"` to `Cargo.toml` and start it with `cargo run`!

```
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};
use termion::event::Key;
use termion::input::TermRead;
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;

fn main() {
    let stdin = stdin();
    //setting up stdout and going into raw mode
    let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
    //printing welcoming message, clearing the screen and going to left top corner with the cursor
    write!(stdout, r#"{}{}ctrl + q to exit, ctrl + h to print "Hello world!", alt + t to print "termion is cool""#, termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1), termion::clear::All)
            .unwrap();
    stdout.flush().unwrap();

    //detecting keydown events
    for c in stdin.keys() {
        //clearing the screen and going to top left corner
        write!(
            stdout,
            "{}{}",
            termion::cursor::Goto(1, 1),
            termion::clear::All
        )
        .unwrap();

        //i reckon this speaks for itself
        match c.unwrap() {
            Key::Ctrl('h') => println!("Hello world!"),
            Key::Ctrl('q') => break,
            Key::Alt('t') => println!("termion is cool"),
            _ => (),
        }

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}
```

## Cross Platform Solution

If you need to support Windows and all other platforms, then you can use **[crossterm](https://crates.io/crates/crossterm)**. It's a pretty decent library and quite heavier than termion. It's **98.06 kB** (as of version 0.16.0).

Here's the same program as above but written using crossterm.

Add this code to `main.rs`, add `crossterm = "0.16.0"` to `Cargo.toml` and try it with `cargo run`!

```
//importing in execute! macro
#[macro_use]
extern crate crossterm;

use crossterm::cursor;
use crossterm::event::{read, Event, KeyCode, KeyEvent, KeyModifiers};
use crossterm::style::Print;
use crossterm::terminal::{disable_raw_mode, enable_raw_mode, Clear, ClearType};
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

fn main() {
    let mut stdout = stdout();
    //going into raw mode
    enable_raw_mode().unwrap();

    //clearing the screen, going to top left corner and printing welcoming message
    execute!(stdout, Clear(ClearType::All), cursor::MoveTo(0, 0), Print(r#"ctrl + q to exit, ctrl + h to print "Hello world", alt + t to print "crossterm is cool""#))
            .unwrap();

    //key detection
    loop {
        //going to top left corner
        execute!(stdout, cursor::MoveTo(0, 0)).unwrap();

        //matching the key
        match read().unwrap() {
            //i think this speaks for itself
            Event::Key(KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char('h'),
                modifiers: KeyModifiers::CONTROL,
                //clearing the screen and printing our message
            }) => execute!(stdout, Clear(ClearType::All), Print("Hello world!")).unwrap(),
            Event::Key(KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char('t'),
                modifiers: KeyModifiers::ALT,
            }) => execute!(stdout, Clear(ClearType::All), Print("crossterm is cool")).unwrap(),
            Event::Key(KeyEvent {
                code: KeyCode::Char('q'),
                modifiers: KeyModifiers::CONTROL,
            }) => break,
            _ => (),
        }
    }

    //disabling raw mode
    disable_raw_mode().unwrap();
}
```

I'm not going to lie, this is a bit harder to read than the `termion` solution, but it does the same job. I have no prior experience with `crossterm` so this code may actually not be the best but it's decent.

Looking for a way to detect only key press without any modifier (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>)? Check this simplified code:

```
//-- code --

loop {
    //--code--

    match read().unwrap() {
        Event::Key(KeyEvent {
            code: KeyCode::Char('a'),
            modifiers: KeyModifiers::NONE,
        }) => //--code--
    }

    //--code--
}

//--code--
```

The important part here is the use of `KeyModifiers::NONE`.

Comment: What about keys without modifiers?  I can't find any examples for crossterm.

Comment: I found you can also do `..` where `modifiers: no_modifiers` is.

Comment: I am very new to Rust. Back in my C/C++ days, I could just use `getch()`,`getchar()` and several other built-in functions for this purpose. In rust, I have to use a third-party library to achieve this? Is it because Rust is still in its infancy or that's the way it is built (with very minimal functionality)?

Comment: @JamesPoulose You can still use `getchar()` in Rust like this: `extern "C" { fn getchar() -> std::os::raw::c_int; }` and omit any third-party libraries, but it is obviously unsafe to do so.

Comment: Running the cross-platform solution in windows 10 using powershell with windows terminal, it does not register any alt+key combos. Any idea why?

Comment: I also tried with cmd and it was unable to detect alt keypresses as well.

Comment: Don't use `KeyModifiers::empty()` because the 2 `no_modifiers` are actually 2 different variables. The 1st is declared but never used and the second is like a wildcard that is used to destructure the enum. Use `KeyModifiers::NONE` instead.

Comment: FYI this does **not** capture keypresses globally. The window/terminal needs to be active.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [console](https://crates.io/crates/console) as a simple cross-platform solution.

```rust
use console::Term;

fn main() {
    let stdout = Term::buffered_stdout();

    'game_loop: loop {
        if let Ok(character) = stdout.read_char() {
            match character {
                'w' => todo!("Up"),
                'a' => todo!("Left"),
                's' => todo!("Down"),
                'd' => todo!("Right"),
                _ => break 'game_loop,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The snippet above shows a basic example for matching common movement characters for a platform.